# Adb hanging on 64 bit linux os

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, 64-bit, adb

I'm trying to use adb on 64 bit linux (Linux Mint 15), and it's simply not working. I installed all the 32 bit libraries other questions of this sort were recommending, but to no avail. Most of the other questions like this seemed to say that adb was giving an error message, but in this case it simply hangs for a long time whenever I give a command. It eventually works, but hangs for quite a while, and I havn't been able to get it to work with eclipse. Does anyone know how I can get it to work smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. My iptables were dropping local loopback network activity, and I changed that with `sudo iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`

Afterwards, adb worked for me.

Comment: Note, if your output rules are set to DROP, you'll probably have to change that too.